# Is this exception logged in TYPO3 and how to push it to Cloudwach

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, typo3, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a web application on an `EC2 instance`. The application is built in `TYPO3 CMS`. Sometimes when I open the web page of the application I get this error:

> Uncaught TYPO3 Exception
>        #1204026251: The temporary cache file "/var/www/htdocs/typo3temp/Cache/Code/fluid_template/324235354.756543529.tmp
>   could not be written

Now I want to make a CloudWatch alarm so that whenever this exception happens I can be notified to make an action and correct this.

My question is: Will I find this error in the file: `/var/www/htdocs/typo3temp/log/typo3.log` even that it is an **UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION** ?

I really need to get this error in `cloudwach` using `awslogs` but I need to push it from a log file in the instance.

Any TYPO3 expert can help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the default message log won't have these errors.

What you want instead is adding a `file` to the system log as can be configured through the TYPO3 Install Tool. If you prefer to do this via `AdditionalConfiguration.php` instead you can use variable paths which work on any system:

```php
// Somewhere outside of the webroot
$logBasePath = dirname(dirname(__DIR__)); // typo3conf -> webroot -> project root
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['systemLog'] = 'file,' . $logBasePath . '/system.log';
```

BTW: Given that you wrote `/var/www/htdocs/typo3temp/log/typo3.log` it sounds like your `typo3.log` is currently exposed to the public assuming that `/var/www/htdocs/` is your web root. You should update TYPO3 to a newer version which adds a random string to the log filename. Preferably you should [move the log file outside of the web root](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Logging/Configuration/Index.html#writer-configuration) altogether.

Comment: I don't expose the log file to the public. I access it by ssh into the EC2 instance. and I don't get you. What this configuration will do ?

Comment: So 'systelLog' will log all the exceptions and errors even uncaught ones?*

Comment: It will log *only* the uncaught ones since the others obviously where properly caught somewhere. ;-)

I've updated my answer wrt public logfile exposure.